# Using A Script Tag File And calling Function From The Script In Angular Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, function, script-tag

I am trying to integrate clover ecommerce iframe into my angular application but am running into an issues. I am trying to get [This](https://codepen.io/davidmarginian/pen/JjXLRwM) example to work the same in my angular projects component but it fails to find the name clover. I looked for a typescript package but could not find one.

The example above is not my code but a sample example code which i want to replicate in one of my angular components.

I put this tag in the index.html file:

```
<script src="https://checkout.sandbox.dev.clover.com/sdk.js">
```

But when creating the clover and elements globally in my component:

```
clover = new Clover('a2c04bd36719c1ae6867d9f978f7cefa');
elements = clover.elements();
```

I get the following error:

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'Clover'.
```

Is there something I am missing? I tried adding the link to the index.html and in the angular.json but that was no luck either. How can I add this script file successfully to my angular project and call its functions?

Comment: the example provided seems to work

Comment: The example is what i want to work on angular. I am trying to duplicate the examples on an angular component but get the error mentioned above. The example is not my code but the code i am trying to move over to my angular project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an external .js file you could use like this:

At your index.html:

```
      <script src="https://checkout.sandbox.dev.clover.com/sdk.js"></script>
</head>
```

At your app.component.ts or any component (.ts):

```
     import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//this is the important line:
    declare const Clover: any;
```

//Example it works:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app-selector-x',
  standalone: true,
  .
  .
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    let clover = new Clover('a2c04bd36719c1ae6867d9f978f7cefa');
    let elements = clover.elements();
    console.dir(clover);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, ill test that in a bit, also would you know how i can add a conditional script. Meaning use this script for development environment and use another script in production. Since the script in this example is loaded in the index.html (like mine), we cannot use an ngif to check the environment and load it based on that. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: You can detect if the process.env is at "development" and make an IF over this, then the angular compiler will exclude from the production code.