# How to use external js file functions for angular template file

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

In my angular app, I have some js files like this: [image: like this]

I added above js file paths to `scripts` array in `angular.json` also. I have a component for owl coursel as below.

```
<!-- banner-section -->
<section class="banner-section p_relative">
    <div class="banner-carousel owl-theme owl-carousel owl-dots-none">
        <div class="slide-item p_relative">
            <div class="bg-layer" style="background-image: url(assets/images/banner/banner-1.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="pattern-layer">
                <div class="pattern-1" style="background-image: url(assets/images/shape/shape-1.png);"></div>
                <div class="pattern-2" style="background-image: url(assets/images/shape/shape-2.png);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="auto-container">
                <div class="content-box">
                    <h2>Open our <span>Current</span> Account Online</h2>
                    <p>This statistic is based on our average personal current account online opening time from the last
                        12 months.</p>
                    <div class="btn-box">
                        <a href="index.html" class="theme-btn btn-one">Make an Appointment</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-item p_relative">
            <div class="bg-layer" style="background-image: url(assets/images/banner/banner-2.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="pattern-layer">
                <div class="pattern-1" style="background-image: url(assets/images/shape/shape-1.png);"></div>
                <div class="pattern-2" style="background-image: url(assets/images/shape/shape-2.png);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="auto-container">
                <div class="content-box">
                    <h2>Open our <span>Current</span> Account Online</h2>
                    <p>This statistic is based on our average personal current account online opening time from the last
                        12 months.</p>
                    <div class="btn-box">
                        <a href="index.html" class="theme-btn btn-one">Make an Appointment</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-item p_relative">
            <div class="bg-layer" style="background-image: url(assets/images/banner/banner-3.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="pattern-layer">
                <div class="pattern-1" style="background-image: url(assets/images/shape/shape-1.png);"></div>
                <div class="pattern-2" style="background-image: url(assets/images/shape/shape-2.png);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="auto-container">
                <div class="content-box">
                    <h2>Open our <span>Current</span> Account Online</h2>
                    <p>This statistic is based on our average personal current account online opening time from the last
                        12 months.</p>
                    <div class="btn-box">
                        <a href="index.html" class="theme-btn btn-one">Make an Appointment</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- banner-section end -->
```

This component needs `owl.js` in my JavaScript files. However, the component does not appear after running the application. When inspecting, I can see the component, but it seems that the JavaScript functions are not executing. They only execute during the initial run of the app. I attempted to log some words to the console, and they were logged successfully.

How I can overcome this?

Comment: what do you mean "the component does not appear after running the application"? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Hi I answer few days similar question how to add external JS, check this out (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77568641/6158032)

Comment: @BizzyBob There aren't any errors in the console. I can't see the component from the browser, but when I inspect it, I can see it there.

Comment: Where are you currently initializing Owl [as described in the docs](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html#call-the-plugin)? I think it should be in the `ngAfterViewInit()` hook.

Comment: does the component show up correctly when you exclude the owl scripts from your angular.json file?  I'm trying to find out if the component not showing up is caused by including the owl script or is it a separate issue?

Comment: you need to share your component ts file as well... some advice: Mixing angular and jQuery will be a long journey, and you should avoid it...

Comment: @SangeethNawarathna There are already pre made angular wrapper packages, for [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-owl-carousel-o?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) it will save you a lot of time!